# Ninject Property Dependency Injection Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller, ninject

I use ASP.NET MVC and Ninject.I try to property injection with ninject in model binder. But it doesn't work. What can I do?

```
/* Model Binding */
public class CartModelBinder:IModelBinder
{
    [Inject]
    public ICartService CartService { get; set; }

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        /* CartService is null here */
        Cart cart = new Cart();
        cart.CartItems = CartService.GetAll(userId);

    }
}

/* Ninject */
    private void AllBllBindings(){
        _kernel = new StandardKernel();
        _kernel.Bind<ICartService>()
                    .To<CartManager>()
                    .WithConstructorArgument("cartDal", new EfCartDal());   
    }
```

Comment: If you are using this in MVC, did you add the Ninject.Web.Mvc package?  As an aside, in the few times I've used Ninject I've had dramatically better success using Constructor injection.

Comment: The responsibility of a `ModelBinder` is to convert your posted data to your model. It should not rely on a service and should not be calling a database.

Comment: What can i do stephen? i have to  get cart items from database.may be i don't use model binder but i want to use it? do you any suggest? David ninject works in my project with constructor injection. my problem is just property injecttion.

Comment: I suspect that `CartModelBinder` is not being instanciated (constructed) by ninject but rather by some other asp.net "magic". Could that be? You can check it out by adding a ctor to `CartModelBinder`, setting a break point and then checking the stack for whether it was called by ninject or not.

Comment: A model binder maps posted values to a model.  That's it.  There is zero need for any database access, since it's only purposes is to provide an object representation of the HTTP posted values.  You probably want your cart management to be a totally separate object that you pass the bound object to.  You don't typically pass an entire cart object to a model binder, you would pass items you want to add to the cart.  Your cart is typically something kept on the server, or in a database, and you only pass the id of it.  Otherwise, it's really easy for people to manipulate the data client side